# Why the number in ddl is not properly passed to the controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In view, I have a dropdownlist control that I fill out by calling a function through a jQuery and DDL is filled correctly and there are no problems so far.

But when I pass the DDL value to the controller, if the value is alphabetical and a number, then the numeric value is not passed.

View:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
     <div class="col-md-10">
        <select id="DDLMachintypeID" name="DDLMachintypeID" class="form-control"></select>
    </div>
</div>

@section MyScripts

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#MachineID').change(function () {
                var machineid = $(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "FillTypes",
                    data: "{MachinKindId:'" + machineid + "'}",
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#DDLMachintypeID').empty();
                        $.each(data, function (i, d) {
                            $('#DDLMachintypeID').append('<option selected="selected" value=' + d + '>' + d + '</option>');
                        });
                    },
                    failure: function (data) {
                        alert('error occured');
                    }

                });
            });
        });
    </script>
End Section
```

and in controller:

```
Dim strDDL = Request.Form("DDLMachintypeID")
```

For example if my dropdown's selected value is `A3`, in controller I get `A`!
Only an alphanumeric string is passed to the controller. The `strDDL` that I read is only `A` while it should be `A3`. Why ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved
This section edited the jquery code in the following format:

```
   $.each(data, function (i, d ) {
                            $('#DDLMachintypeID').append('<option selected="selected" value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>');
                        });
```